# Iterate through elements in a string

Tags: javascript, string, iterator

I am using javascript. Now i have a string in java which is "[\"x\",\"y\"]". Now i want to use this in javascript. Please find the code below:

```
String str = "[\"x\",\"y\"]";
<script>
  var javaScriptVar = '<%= str%>'

</script>
```

Now i want to iterate for each element in str. I am using :

```
$.each(javaScriptVar, function (i, itemI) {
   //do something
}
```

But i am getting the following error in console:

```
Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in ["x","y"].
```

How do i make this iterable? Is that because it is considering as a string? How to make it as an array in javascript to iterate through the elements in that?

Comment: `javaScriptVar.split('');` will transform your string into an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just to avoid the quotes around to make it an object(JSON is a valid object representation in Javascript) otherwise you cant use [`jQuery.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) method on a string. The error is throwing since it looks for `length` property using [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) but it won't work with a string.

```
var javaScriptVar = <%= str%>
```

---

Or parse the JSON string and provide it as the argument.

```
$.each(JSON.parse(javaScriptVar), function (i, itemI) {
   //do something
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment. Removing the quotes solved the issue. @PranavCBalan

Comment: @user3750720 : glad to help you :)